# CSS grid and responsive view

Tags: html, css, media-queries, css-grid

I just started learning the CSS grid today, and I can start seeing the point to use this awesome css classes. But one thing that really is confusing me, is how to reorganize the grid on mobile devices.

I made an example below here. That is working how it should on a desktop view. When the screen size is going below 991px. I would like the grid was looking like this:

[image]

But how should I control that using the CSS grid?

```css
.wrapper {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 2fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows:minmax(100px,auto);
  grid-gap:1em;
} 

.wrapper > div {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 1em;
}
.wrapper > div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.box1 {
  grid-column:1/3;
  grid-row:1/3;
}

.box2 {
  grid-column:3;
}

.box3 {
  grid-column:3;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="box box1">Box 1</div>
    <div class="box box2">Box 2</div>
    <div class="box box3">Box 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `@media` and you need to make again adjustments for 991px.

```css
.wrapper {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 2fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows:minmax(100px,auto);
  grid-gap:1em;
} 

.wrapper > div {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 1em;
}
.wrapper > div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.box1 {
  grid-column:1/3;
  grid-row:1/3;
}

.box2 {
  grid-column:3;
}

.box3 {
  grid-column:3;
}

@media screen and (max-width:991px){

  .wrapper {
    grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
  } 
  .box1 {
    grid-column:1/4;
    grid-row:1/3;
  }

  .box2 {
    grid-column:1/2;
  }

  .box3 {
    grid-column:2/4;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="box box1">Box 1</div>
    <div class="box box2">Box 2</div>
    <div class="box box3">Box 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use *media queries* with `@media only screen and (max-width: 990px)` -
 you can use a two-column *grid* using `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr` for this view - see demo below:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

.wrapper>div {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 1em;
}

.wrapper>div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.box1 {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 1/3;
}

.box2 {
  grid-column: 3;
}

.box3 {
  grid-column: 3;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 990px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
  .box1 {
    grid-column: span 2; /* span the first row */
    grid-row: 1; /* first row */
  }
  .box2 {
    grid-column: 1; /* first column */
  }
  .box3 {
    grid-column: 2; /* second column */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box box1">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box box2">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box box3">Box 3</div>
</div>
```